# Add "Good Luck Girl" as a tag synonym?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

While writing my question on *Good Luck Girl!*, I noticed that the tag is currently set to [binbou-gami-ga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binbou-gami-ga), and doesn't appear to have any synonyms. However, [at least on Funimation](http://www.funimation.com/shows/good-luck-girl/home), the anime title is given as *Good Luck Girl!*, so I'm inclined to suggest that `good-luck-girl` be added as a synonym. (It's worth noting that on [Hulu](http://www.hulu.com/binbogami-ga), the name "Binbougami ga" is kept. The first usage is also seen on Funimation clips on YouTube, such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPtKMbtHbtc).)

However, since I have written exactly zero answers for that tag, I can't suggest tag synonyms on the tag page (and so am mentioning this here). (Also feel free to retag this question if I've tagged it improperly).

Comment: Can you add links to sources in your post?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: added some links to Funimation and info about the usage on Hulu

Comment: Madman (AU) seems to be using [Good Luck Girl!](http://www.madman.com.au/news/karneval-and-good-luck-girl/) as well with a subtitle "Binbogami ga!". I can't say I've ever heard "Good Luck Girl" before now, but if that's what it's licensed as in most places, we should probably use it for the main tag name.